# Do all the eminent computer scientists use LaTeX and friends?

Tags: discussion, community

I am not sure if this belonged to the main site. I am putting it here to be on the safe side.

Use of TeX/LaTeX have been pioneered by the computer scientists and mathematicians. Now, it is no longer confined to any group of people of a particular major.

I understand that the short answer to my question in subject should be, "No." When I say *all*, there must be some exceptions. However, as an avid user of LaTeX (originally TeX), I find it somewhat mentally shocking for me when I find the exceptions.

Here are a few.

- As we find [here](http://www.troff.org/pubs.html#cn), [Andrew S. Tanenbaum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum) mentions "... Troff, which, after all these years, is still the only way to go". (However, the 5th edition of the same book is silent about this point).

There are some more at the [same site](http://www.troff.org/pubs.html), majority of which are in the field of Computer Science, by important scholars.

- In his [speech](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-2/tb98knut.pdf), [Donald E. Knuth](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/), mentions not preparing a PowerPoint presentation. That implicitly means he does not use `beamer`. (See, page 121, left column, last but one parenthesized paragraph.)

What could be other important mentionables?

Comment: DEK uses plain (unsurprisingly), so he's not likely to use `beamer`!

Comment: @JosephWright I never expected DEK to deviate from plain. That is why I did not even mention it. But the PP/beamer part is _not_ the unsurprising part.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is on-topic: it's not about TeX-sx (so not for meta), and I'm not sure if it's answerable on the main site.

Comment: @JosephWright I could not decide either. But I believe that this is something we can definitely discuss. In the main site we have discussed [beautiful LaTeX examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends). And see [this similar discussion](http://www.fountainpennetwork.com/forum/index.php/topic/102492-famous-peoples-pens/), though very much on a different topic.

Comment: @MMA I've decided to vote-to-close this as off-topic. If it were on the main site, I would vote for primarily opinion-based or unclear what you're asking. This question is well-suited for a discussion board, but not for a Q&A site ;) Notice that none of the two posts you provide is a good "judicate" for this one: the "beautiful examples" question is one of the best CW question on the whole SE network, because it has many good answers that serve good purpose; there's no purpose in knowing that Alibaba uses beamer while Nikola Šuhaj uses powerpoint. The 2nd one is not even on SE, so whatever.

Comment: @tohecz I will refrain for voting either way since I was not so sure about where to put the question, the main site or the meta. But as an avid LaTeX user, this was something I wanted to know about. I knew that the second example I mentioned above (FPN) one was not at SE. That was purposely included to show that if some people feel strongly about something, they will want to know the many facets of it.

Comment: I think the question is off topic here (and "too broad" on the main site)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps I agree with you on both the points. But I will still want to know the issue in the question. Why are we so hesitant to discuss it?

Comment: @MMA it's not that we are hesitant, it's that there is nothing to discuss. As you say in the question itself, the answer to the question as written is clearly No. If you changed "All" to "most" the answer would depend on the meaning of "most" and "eminent" if you changed "all" to "some" the answer is clearly yes.